# QXcbConnection error while try to install QT package on Ubuntu 18, Linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, package, display

I have Ubuntu 18 on mu VMware software and try to install QT based on  [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeSKJC3s1Vc). The issue is when I want to run the following command:

`sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.11.3.run`

I get this error:

> QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
>   QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
>   Aborted

Any help?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might simply be a case of the `DISPLAY` environment variable not being set.

Try `ssh` with `X11` forwarding rather than `sudo`.  So something like...

```
ssh -X root@localhost <full-path-to>/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.11.3.run
```